# Возможно ли писать GUI на .NET в линуксе

Tags: c#, linux, wpf, .net

Хотел попробовать перейти на линукс, но никак не могу разобраться с разработкой wpf, смотрел авалонию, но там все по-другому. Так же не нашел никакого xaml превью (как вообще без этого можно жить?). Есть ли какие-либо варианты, или надо сидеть на винде и не выпендриваться?

Comment: на .net писать под линукс можно, на WPF нельзя.

Comment: тогда чем можно заменить WPF?

Comment: Авалонией, смирившись с тем, что "там все по-другому"

Comment: WPF не заменить ничем, но можно попробовать да, как выше советуют, Авалонию.

Comment: Ну или вот MAUI, правда хз насколько оно юзабельное, я сам не пробовал https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: @tym32167 официальной поддержки линукса нет :(

Comment: @andreymal о, точно, тогда печальная печаль

Comment: @tym32167 MAUI официально не работает под линуксами, так что если только неофициальные сборки. Не любят мелкомягкие линукс. Но прикрутить говорят не космически сложно.

Comment: Gtk можно, но оно превратит ваш код на сишарпе в "си без плюсов" на сишарпе)

Comment: @aepot не, понятно, что раз мак и андроид держит, значит и линукс в теории может. Но без офиц поддержки лепить костыли это такое :)

Comment: Авалония проще WPF, советую перейти. Превью есть.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Linux desktop GUI:

- [**Avalonia**](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia): опенсорсная кросс-платформенная версия WPF, 35-й диалект XAML.
- [**MAUI**](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux): форк MAUI под Linux, наследник Xamarin.Forms, 36-й диалект XAML.
- [**Blazor Hybrid**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/): для ценителей подхода Electron с превращением всех программ в браузер с локальным сервером.
- [**Gtk#**](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp): WinForms по отношению к Windows — как Gtk по отношению к Линуксу.
- [**Uno**](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno): кросс-платформенная версия UWP/WinUI, 37-й диалект XAML.
- [**WinForms**](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/): костыль с подпорками эпохи Mono всё ещё реально завести на Linux через Mono, но Core не будет.
- [**Qml.NET**](https://github.com/qmlnet/qmlnet): заброшенная попытка перетащить современный Qt в .NET, ещё где-то валялись биндинги для ископаемого Qt.